# jquery, css: изменение высоты поля ввода в зависимости от объёма вводимого текста

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать следующий эффект:
При вводе текста в поле с каждой новой строкой (или переносом текста) высота поля ввода (и, опционально, его родителя) увеличивается (до определённого предела).

Есть ли автоматические средства для реализации такого поведения?

Или требуется отслеживать ввод текста в поле, получать из него текст, определять размеры поля и выставлять новые размеры, такими чтоб не был прокруток?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такое можно достичь с помощью Javascript. Взято c enSO с [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48460773/1548895):

```html
<textarea name="text" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + "px"'></textarea>
```

Comment: В общем неплохо, с некоторыми допиливаниями (на максимальную и минимальную высоту) сойдет. Непонятно только откуда всегда берется небольшая прокрутка, как-будто не хватает несколько пикселей в высоту чтобы прокрутки не было.

Тут, как я понимаю, тот же принцип что я описал выше - ловить ввод текст и перерассчитывать высоту

Comment: @Zhihar А в каком это браузере скролл добавляется? А то я в Chrome такого не наблюдаю. Принцип такой же, который вы описали (тут, в принципе, вряд ли можно было бы по-другому сделать).

Comment: в Chrome и добавлялся, удалось это побороть, когда полю добавил `padding` небольшой, так что непонятно, почему он немного скроллил.